# PCB Polygon current calculator?

Tags: current, pcb-design, eaglecad

There are tools to calculate the width of a trace for a certain amount of current, but what about **polygons**?
Do you know a **tool**, possibly for **Eagle Cad**, that quickly calculates the maximum **current** or at least the **area** of the polygon?
If I have the polygon area, then I guess I can calculate the current using the formulas from [trace-width-calculator](https://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html):

```
Area[mils^2] = (Current[Amps]/(k*(Temp_Rise[deg. C])^b))^(1/c)

Then, the Width is calculated:

Width[mils] = Area[mils^2]/(Thickness[oz]*1.378[mils/oz])

For IPC-2221 internal layers: k = 0.024, b = 0.44, c = 0.725

For IPC-2221 external layers: k = 0.048, b = 0.44, c = 0.725

where k, b, and c are constants resulting from curve fitting to the IPC-2221 curves
```

EDIT 1:
Example polygon:

[image]

Comment: I think current will be limited to the narrowest width, no? i.e. Adding a large copper block to a 10mil trace = ampacity of a 10mil trace.

Comment: Thanks @rdtsc, that's an helpful hint. I've added an example of a polygon as image in my question. Does the red marked distance (shortest side of polygon) determine the max current?

Comment: Current will not flow evenly though a short polygon fill. It looks like in this one it will flow from the via field to the large plated through hole. I would say the width should be measured more or less perpendicular to the straight line between through hole and via field. The current will concentrate in the shortest path, but the extra copper will help spread heat dissipation over a wider area so that is good. I hope you do not plan to have a high current flow in/out of the lone via in the upper left corner of the polygon. Poor little guy.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there are tools that given the geometry of the conductor and the current, calculates the current density at any point along the interconnect.

Comment: @mkeith: thanks, I see. There is no high current flow through the via upper left.

Comment: @SteveSh: can you name some examples? I'll have a look, thanks!

Comment: @haku15 - The Hyperlynx Power Integrity tool (part of the Mentor Graphics tool suite) is one.  Ansys Maxwell (think I have this right) is another one.  You could also build a piece-wise mode in Spice, but would have to enter the resistance information for each segment by hand.